# Lush Slider full width and restricted height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I believe I have tried about everything and am failing miserably. I have been working with the lush responsive slider and have been having some major issues.

To start off I took the exact code from the demo and placed it in my header, but it had a strange padding on the bottom and right side so I removed it and thought it was working fine except for the height. It's so large that it takes over more than half the page.

When I resized the window and reloaded the page though the background of the slider sat in the top left corner much smaller than it needed to be. So the responsiveness only works if you reload at 100% screen? That doesn't make any scenes.

Also, the height is bothering me. I cannot get it to resize at all and when I did put static heights on the ul and li of 10em it did resize, but then the responsiveness went out the window.

I tried to post this in a js fiddle, but the plugin was so much code that it crashed it without running anything. If it would help I can post a dev site with this on it. As I said I used the exact html and css from the demo files I only took away a bit of padding to make it full width.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Include the plugin in the js fiddle using a link to the file. Then try again.

Comment: Thats what I was doing and I couldn't get it to load. The browser kept timing out. I did post it on my dev site, I put it in the main question.

Comment: Ok then, two things. One: it looks like the jquery is setting a size on the actual element. (adding `style="height=##px"`) two, make sure you set the size of both the UL and LI in the css. Obviously, inline styles overwrite your CSS, but It's in the jquery adding that when the image becomes active. (I believe this is whats happening anyway)

Comment: That is what I believe is happening as well. Except I have no idea where it's setting that height. And I did try and add inline styles to both the ul and li, but it messed p the responsiveness

Comment: You don't want to add more styles, you want to change what is there. Give me a min, I'm trying to un-minimize your js/css.

Comment: Which js file is the one that came with the plugin?

Comment: All of them haha... but I believe its within jquery.lush.min.js

Comment: Haha, I was looking for it in the header.

Comment: Ok, so you need to look for any reference to the hight of the class `.lush` and `.lush-slider` in the CSS files and make sure the hight is set to what you want. Then go into the js files and find where it is resizing the objects and change that. I'd give more details, but I've got to run. In the js, it refers to the object as `this`. Hopefully you know jquery, you'll be able to fix it quick :D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I have managed to work out a solution for the width issue. The problem seems to relate to the initial baseWidth, which defaults to 1140 pixels. Playing around with the

```
data-base-width="600" and data-base-height="600"
```

attributes in the first lush slider div tag may see you make some progress, but it looks like only fixed values are accepted, no percentages. I opted for this solution which seems to work, write the first div tag using document.write method and programmaticaly set the width the the clientWidth, as such :

```
<script>
document.write('<div id="lushDiv" class="lush-slider autoload shadow-a" data-slider-pause-on-hover="true" data-base-width="' + document.body.clientWidth + '" data-base-height="600" style="background: rgb(229, 229, 229)">');
</script>
```

Comment: Hey! I'm glad you found a solution to this! Way long ago I had contacted the creator of the plugin and had found a very long and drawn out solution that just barely worked. I'm no longer on that project or I would switch to this since it seems a lot cleaner! :)

Answer (score -1):

My suggestion is not to use Javascript or JQuery. Some simple CSS and HTML will do.

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jacobdubail/bKaxg/7/

You obviously don't need all of the CSS. Just change it to accompany your layout.

Change your width to percentages, like so:

```
min-width: 100%;
```

I would suggest changing the height to ems.

Comment: This will actually not work. When I was working with this, this was what I first tried. Of course the best thing to do in any situation is to try and use css, but this is a bit more complicated than that because the jQuery is what is manipulating the height and width. I ended up do a very very complex fix for this.

Comment: Set the height in CSS

Comment: Yes, I got what you were saying, but the jQuery set by the lush slider overrides it. That is why you have to use jQuery to fix this.

Comment: What I'm saying is, DO NOT USE the JQUERY LUSH. Just delete everything you got for that and re-do it using just Html and CSS. Using the JQUERY LUSH slows down the page and it's a bunch of unnecessary code.

Comment: But that was not my question here. I am trying to use the lush plugin. My company bought it and I have to use it. And it does not slow down the page at all, it is a very fast slider. Have you ever actually looked at it? This is not just a go to the next picture slider... http://geedmo.com/?item=LushSlider